# How to order the second column from smallest to largest if the first column is equal rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to display the concentrations in ascending order (smallest to largest) if the temperature is equalled.

Here a table:

| T | C |

|     1        |      3       |

|     1       |       2       |

|     1        |      4       |

Gas Analyte Model

```
class GasAnalyte < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :gas_groups
    has_many :response_forms
end
```

Gas Group Model

```
class GasGroup < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :gas_analyte
    has_many :concentrations
    has_many :temperatures
end
```

Concentration Model

```
class Concentration < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :gas_group
    has_many :response_forms
    validates :value
end
```

Temperature Model

```
class Temperature < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :gas_group
    has_many :response_forms
    validates :value
end
```

ResponseForm Model

```
class ResponseForm < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :temperature
    belongs_to :concentration
    belongs_to :gas_analyte
    belongs_to :gas_group
end
```

View

```
<tbody>
    <%= form.fields_for :response_forms do |f| %>
        <%= render partial: 'fields', locals: {f: f} %>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

form is a gas analyte

fields View

```
<tr>
    <% res = ResponseForm.find(f.object.id) %>
    <td><%= Temperature.find(res.temperature.id).value %></td>
    <td><%= Concentration.find(res.concentration.id).value %></td>
<tr>
```

What could I do?

Comment: Do you want to order by temperature, then by concentration? (If so, just sort the arrays `[t,c]`.) If not, and if the rows are already grouped by temperature (but the groups not necessarily ordered by temperature), do you only want to order the rows of each temperature group by concentration? Your question, incidentally, is very nicely laid out and written.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to order the rows of each temperature group by concentration.

Comment: Is this for a show view only? Where is each `form` defined by the time we get to the view you've shown?  Is it a collection of `@forms` that is being looped over? That is probably where you want to do your ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your outer partial you want to specify the sorting of the response forms. This can be done by ordering them and then passing them into the `fields_for`:

```
<tbody>
    <% sorted_fields = f.object.response_forms.left_join(:temperature, :concentration).order('temperatures.value', 'concentrations.value') %>
    <%= form.fields_for :response_forms, sorted_fields do |f| %>
        <%= render partial: 'fields', locals: {f: f} %>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

If this ordering is something you will frequently use,  it would probably be worth moving into a scope in the `ResponseForm` model:

```rb
class ResponseForm < ApplicationModel

    scope :tc_ordering, -> { left_join(:temperature, :concentration).order('temperatures.value', 'concentrations.value') }

end

# in your partial:
<%= form.fields_for :response_forms, f.object.response_forms.tc_ordering do |f| %>
```